# Problems using SmartGIT - Unable to auto-detect email address

Tags: git, smartgit

Yesterday I decided to try out SmartGIT to manage my code when a friend suggested I should use SmartGIT.

After installing it and trying it out (successfully) I thought I was set until today when I tried to commit code and I got the error message "unable to auto-detect email address (got 'User@Computer-name.(none)').

I checked the GIT config and everything is set properly, yet I continue to get this message.

Anyone else experience these kind of problems?

Comment: What OS you are using, what Git version? If on Windows, where is your global .gitconfig located?

Comment: You wrote you've used SmartGit successfully, but "today" it failed to commit. Does anything changed on your system configuration?

Comment: Win 7, Git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0 and I'm unsure how to find out where SmartGIT places the .gitconfig file. I'm new to Git, hence why I'm using a GUI instead of just command line.

Comment: You may post the text you wrote under "Edit" as own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting in touch with the makers of SmartGIT, they pointed out that my PC was pointing to a git config file in a old folder I used before. Also, my `HOME` variable was set to point to this folder, causing this weird conflict seeing as SmartGIT (apparently) looks for your .gitconfig file in the `%USERNAME%` folder. Just moved my .gitconfig to that folder and it worked.

Comment: So I am added the [user] section to the gitconfig at both places, in the Git installation directory and also under c:\users\myname\gitconfig. But I still see unknown when I try to commit. Is there anything else that needs to be changed ?

When I do git config --user.name, it does show me the correct name. 

P.S: I am using SmartGit for my commits.

Answer (score 3):

I am completely frustrated:

A. Because this also happened  to me and

B. Because the answer in this thread is exceptionally vague.

As far as I could understand you need to put .gitconfig file into you C:/Documents and Settings/USERNAME folder but I:

1) cannot find any .gitconfig file (I searched the entire system) only gitconfig and gitconfig.vim and

2) placing those two files into the aforementioned folder did no good to me.

I have a request for developers: though this issue seems rare, could you please provide an option for a CLEAN UNINSTALL of smartgit as well as CLEAN INSTALL, that recreates EVERY config file necessary. I thought that is a natural practice and was shocked to see such mistakes prop up due to the fact that you do not follow it.

SOLUTION: Ok, so to solve the problem I launched [GIT_FOLDER]/git/git-cmd.bat which launched the command line and entered the commands from the error. Precisely I entered:

git config --global user.email "[MY_EMAIL]"

and

git config --global user.name "[MY_NAME]"

Though I think I entered the same e-mail as the one I gave when I first install the program (to register the non-commercial copy) I don't think they ever asked me for the name then, so the name was completely new. Therefore I don't know if you need to enter the precise e-mail you gave at the first install or not.

After that I restarted Git and commit behavior worked ok.

Comment: _The question has been closed so I'm putting a comment_.

When using git _directly_ I had no issue: proper `.gitconfig` file was fetched from the `HOME` directory. From SmartGit it was not the case, so I had to configure it by adding the property `smartgit.executable.home=/path/to/home` (forward slashes __mandatory__) to the file `smartgit.properties`.

Sources: [SmartGit - Changing SmartGit's $HOME](http://smartgit.3668570.n2.nabble.com/Changing-SmartGit-s-HOME-td7575666.html), [SmartGit - Git Client: Documentation](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/documentation/6.5/?page=system-properties)